How to hide all UI Elements in Cesium?
I am trying to hide all elements in Cesium to get a plain UI. I have experimented with different properties in the JS API but wasn't able to remove all the UI elements and just keep the Earth Globe. Is there any way I can do this?

Instead of hiding all elements, you can use this code snippet.
const widget = new Cesium.CesiumWidget("cesiumContainer");



One way to solve this is by using css, here is a property which I used to hide all Cesium UI elements
/* hide cesium elements */
.cesium-viewer-animationContainer, .cesium-viewer-timelineContainer, .cesium-viewer-bottom, .cesium-viewer-fullscreenContainer, .cesium-viewer-toolbar {
  display: none !important;
}

